# Angular & Firebase - Possible to create an auth guard that checks if the user is on a login screen?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- An Auth Guard that performs a router redirect based on conditions

**Where I've got to**

- I have an auth guard on many of the components that if the users has a bookmark (for example...) to url and navigate to it whilst not logged in, they will be pushed back to the login page.

**Question**

- Is it possible to modify my auth guard so that if the user is logged in, but somehow manages to navigate to 'www.mydomain.com/login' that they are redirected to a specified route?

**My Route Guard**

I've left my commented out code where I've tried out some logic. The issue here is that if I use the commented out code, if the user isn't logged in, it ends up in a loop of redirecting back to the login page that you're already on.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


//testing
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()

export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth
  ) { }




  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.auth.authState
      .take(1)
      .map(authState => !!authState)
      .do(auth => !auth ? this.router.navigate(['/login']) : true);
    
  }



  // canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  //   return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
  // }

  // checkLoggedIn(url: string) {

  //   if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
  //     console.log("yup, i'm logged in!");
  //     return true;
  //   } else {
  //     this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  //     console.log("nop, i'm not logged in!");
  //     return false;
  //   }
  // }


}
```

**Example of auth guard on a route**

Ideally, I'd like some logic in my auth guard which means I can do the same below on the login route

```js
    {
        path: 'folders',
        component: FolderListComponent,
        resolve: { folderListData: FolderListResolver },
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
    },
```

**UPDATE**
Getting a little closer thanks to @Vega. What happens now:

- Login page > sign in > redirected to correct page = Great!
- Navigate to any page apart from login whilst not signed in = redirected back to login page = Great!
- Navigate to login screen whilst signed in = Stuck. It now thinks the user isn't logged in = This needs fixing

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let newUrl = state.url;
    if (newUrl === "/login") {
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        console.log('Login Page / Signed In');
        return false;
      }
      else {
        console.log('Login Page / Not Signed In');
        return true;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        console.log('Other Page / Signed In');
        return true
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        console.log('Other Page / Not Signed In');
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered this :   { path: "abc", redirectTo: 'login'} ?

Comment: Redirecting to the login page when I'm not signed in isn't the issue. That's all sorted. My issue is redirecting the user to say the 'folder' route on the off chance they are logged in and navigate to 'domain.com/login'. As they are already logged in, I don't want them on that route.

Comment: I am still not getting, be patient, please. Is the logic the follwoing: if the user is logged in, he should've be redirected to login page and instead to an other or stay at the same page?

Comment: No problem. I appreciate the time:) If user is logged in AND somehow navigated back to /login, redirect to the /folder route. That's it. I have everything else handled. If the user isn't signed in, my auth guard pushes them back to the login page.

Comment: How about a router listener with url checking? if the user is logged in and the new url is '/login', don't route

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
This may be not the more elegant way, but it works, and is less code:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let newUrl = state.url;
    if (newUrl === "/login") {
      if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
        //this.router.navigate([oldUrl]);
        //logged and routing to /login => go back. this probably need to be improved!
        this.location.back();
        return false
      }
      else {
        //not logged => go /login
        return true
      }
    }
   // here is the 'traditional' part of the guard
    else {
      if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
        return true
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Old answer:**

In main component:

```
 ngOnInit() {

        if (isPlatformBrowser) {
            this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
                .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
                .subscribe(() => {
                    let url = window.location.toString();
                    if (url.indexOf("/login") && loggedIn)
                      //do whatever is necessary
                    }
                    else{
                       this.router.navigate(['login']);
               }
                });
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Or something like the following:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnOtherGuard] },
```

and

in AnOtherGuard

```
 ....
 canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
      this.location.back(); //or whatever is necessary
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Vega. I'm exceptionally new to this. What is 'isPlatformBrowser'? Also I'm integrating it with 'canActivate' in the router (as seen in my code above) Any way of integrating it into that?

Comment: Just add on top import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
and for the guard, if have defined it in your routes, the router will take care of it

Comment: @MegaTron, I slightly changed my previous snippet to help and added an other one, please check

Comment: Thanks Vega. I appreciate the time. Is there no way to include any logic in my current auth guard? It'd be nice to have everything in one place.

Comment: Ah, I am not as good at routing, but accept the challenge ;) I will see what can be done

Comment: ah, you're amazing. Thank you. The issue i've been having is that if the user is logged in and ends up at 'domain.com/login' (through a bookmark or something..) they just see a blank login screen because they are already logged in. However, if I have 'if not logged in, route back to login screen' it ends up looping on itself.

Comment: The code I have above is a routing / auth guard. It works on all components except the login page. If the user isn't signed in and navigates to any URL, they will be pushed back to the login page. I need logic so that if the user IS logged and they navigate to '/login', then it redirects them to '/folders'

Comment: Thanks Vega! It's getting close. But it doesn't work fully on my end. I've made an update to my original post.

Comment: Good:) Have you add the guard on login router: like canActivate: [AuthGuard] ? It works on my end though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152822/discussion-between-megatron-and-vega).